# Find out what's using port 80 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, port80

I'm having trouble running a service on port 80 since it seems to be already in use by another program. Problem is, using nestat -lpn | grep :80 (or variants of this command) does not show any process using port 80.

I'm runnning Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, on an unknown VM provided by my school. Supposedly they do not impose any kind of restrictions, so the server is considered to behave like a physical box connected directly to the internet.

As I've already stated, greping netstat for port 80 does not produce any output even as sudo. Just to make sure its working right greping for port 22 brings up sshd. Ports 8080 and 443 also appear to be in use but don't show up on netstat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does your error indicate that it's really in use, or are you just not able to open a socket?

Just an idea, but are you trying to run it as root? Port 80 is kinda special, so you might give it a try. In fact all ports under 1024 are protected to be opened only by root.

Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Wow, that was the soundest advice I've gotten yet, and to think I've got friends that administer linux servers for a living. Will try when I get the chance. I'm pretty sure the ports are in use by something since they also appear as open when I run a port scan on my IP.

Comment: Ok so even though I can see port 80, 8080 and 443 open when port-scanning (although none of them connect) it seems that running as root did the trick and I'm now able to run my service. Thanks for the info, Xavier.

Comment: You're welcome! You can always vote for my answer if you liked it ;-)

Comment: Awesome. Excellent answer!! It really worked for me. Thanks a lot!